# Stuck on multithreading java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

So this code is giving multiple errors in main. Can someone tell me whats wrong with this?

the question is to create consumer and producer threads to make a lamp. only two consumers are allowed and theres a producer thread for every component of the lamp

```
public class ProducerConsumerTest{




    public static void main(String[] args){

        StartProducer startproducer = new StartProducer();
        System.out.println("Start producer calling");
        startproducer.start();


    }
}
class StartProducer extends Thread{

    Screw screw = new Screw();
    Base base = new Base();
    Stand stand = new Stand();
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    LightBulb lightbulb = new LightBulb();
    int screws = screw.screwcount;
    int bases = base.basecount;
    int stands = stand.standcount;
    int sockets = socket.socketcount;
    int lightbulbs = lightbulb.bulbcount;
    Consumer1 consumer1 = new Consumer1();
    Consumer2 consumer2 = new Consumer2();
    public synchronized void run(){

        System.out.println("producer test");

            screw.start();


            base.start();


            stand.start();


            socket.start();


            lightbulb.start();




        boolean possible = possibleToBuildLamp(screws,bases,stands,sockets,lightbulbs);
        if(possible == true){
            consumer1.start();
            consumer2.start();

        }
    }

    private boolean possibleToBuildLamp(int screws, int bases, int stands,
            int sockets, int lightbulbs) {
        if(screws>=4 && bases>=1 && stands>=1 && sockets>=3 && lightbulbs>=3){
            return true;
        }

        else return false;
    }

}
class Screw extends Thread{

    public int screwcount;
     public synchronized void run(){
         while(true){
         if(screwcount>=0 && screwcount<7){
             screwcount++;
         }
         try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

}
}

class Base extends Thread{
    public int basecount;
    public synchronized void run(){

    while(true){
         if(basecount>=0 && basecount <2){
             basecount++;
         }
         try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}

class Stand extends Thread {
    public int standcount;
    public synchronized void run(){

    while(true){
         if(standcount>=0 && standcount<2){
             standcount++;
         }
    }

}
}

class Socket extends Thread {
    public int socketcount;
    public synchronized void run(){

    while(true){
         if(socketcount>=0 && socketcount<7){
             socketcount++;
         }
         try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}

class LightBulb extends Thread {
    public int bulbcount;
    public synchronized void run(){

    while(true){

         if(bulbcount>=0 && bulbcount<4){
             bulbcount++;
         }
         try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}



class Consumer1 extends Thread {
    ProducerConsumerTest test = new ProducerConsumerTest();
    StartProducer start = new StartProducer();


    public synchronized void run(){
        while(true){
        Screw screw = new Screw();
        Base base = new Base();
        Stand stand = new Stand();
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        LightBulb lightbulb = new LightBulb();

        screw.screwcount-=4;
        base.basecount-=1;
        stand.standcount-=1;
        socket.socketcount-=3;
        lightbulb.bulbcount-=3;
        System.out.println("one lamp made");
        start.notify();

        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }


    }


}

class Consumer2 extends Thread {
ProducerConsumerTest test = new ProducerConsumerTest();
StartProducer start = new StartProducer();

    public synchronized void run(){

        while(true){
        Screw screw = new Screw();
        Base base = new Base();
        Stand stand = new Stand();
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        LightBulb lightbulb = new LightBulb();

        screw.screwcount-=4;
        base.basecount-=1;
        stand.standcount-=1;
        socket.socketcount-=3;
        lightbulb.bulbcount-=3;
        System.out.println("One lamp made");
        start.notify();
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: *"first time poster so please be gentle"* - Gently: instead of just saying "this code is giving multiple errors in main", you should say what the errors are, or at least what *kind* of error they are.

Answer (score 0):

In main you create a `StartProducer`:

```
StartProducer startproducer = new StartProducer();
```

which creates a `Consumer1`:

```
Consumer1 consumer1 = new Consumer1();
```

which creates another new `StartProducer`:

```
StartProducer start = new StartProducer();
```

which will new create another new `Consumer1`. It will not be able to do anything else, because it gets stuck creating an infinite line of `StartProducer`s creating `Consumer1`s, until it bottles out with a StackOverlowError. Likewise for `Consumer2`, if it were able to get as far as creating those.

If you only want one `StartProducer` object, you need to create it in a single place, and pass the reference to it to the other objects that need it, such as by making it a parameter to their constructors or placing it in a shared variable where they can access it.

P.S. All of your thread's `run()` methods are `synchronized`, which doesn't achieve any mutual exclusion, because every thread is synchronizing on a different object: that thread itself. If you want to provide useful mutual exclusion, you will need to use a [synchronized statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) to synchronize on a specific object shared by multiple threads.